# Solving equations in Sagemath

Tags: sage, equation-solving

I have to find a vector and a matrix that transform some input vectors into others. The input vectors are:  (−3, 4), (0, 8) i (6, 6) and the output for each vector is (1, −4), (6, −4) i (8, 2).

That's what i've tried:
`

```
var('a b c d e f')
p = matrix([[-3,4],[0,8],[6,6]]).T
p2 = matrix([[1,-4],[6,-4],[8,2]]).T
q = vector([a,b])
t = matrix([[c,d],[e,f]])

eqs = [p2[i,j] == q[i] + t[i,:]*p[:,j] for i in range(2) for j in range(2)]
show(eqs)

solve(eqs,[a,b,c,d,e,f])
```

But when i say show(eqs) the output is [False,False,False,False] instead of the actual equations. Why?

I've tried the code above. I expect some feedback that can make me understand the error in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding scalars and matrices: `p2[i,j]` is a scalar, as is `q[i]`, but `t[i,:]*p[:,j]` is a `1x1` matrix: `type(p2[1,1])` will return `<class 'sage.rings.integer.Integer'>` and `type(q[0])` will return `<class 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression'>`, but `type(t[i,:]*p[:,j])` will return `<class 'sage.matrix.matrix_symbolic_dense.Matrix_symbolic_dense'>`. Try using the only entry in that matrix instead, either by explicitly pulling out the `[0,0]` entry or by converting the row of `t` and the column of `p2` to vectors and using a dot product: use

```
eqs = [p2[i,j] == q[i] + (t[i,:]*p[:,j])[0,0] for i in range(2) for j in range(2)]
```

or

```
eqs = [p2[i,j] == q[i] + t[i]*p.transpose()[j] for i in range(2) for j in range(2)]
```